# Image gallery hover overlay height problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm trying to recreate a google image search layout with an image hover overlay effect. 
The problem I'm facing is setting the correct height of the overlay, I managed to set the correct width via jQuery but I can't seem to get the height right. I'd like the overlay to fill the entire image and not only the top.

An example of the image hover overlay effect can be found here: [Image hover overlay effect](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp)

Here is my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ripsey/w18qc679/), hover on top of the images to see the effect.

```js
function picRow(selector) {

            masterArray = [];

            // create each lineArray and push it to masterArray 
            $(selector).each(function () {

                // get "selector" css px value for margin-bottom 
                // - parse out a floating point number 
                // - and divide by the outer width to get a decimal percentage
                margin = (parseFloat($(this).css("margin-bottom"), 10)) / ($(this).outerWidth());
                marginRight = margin * 100 + "%";
                // subtract subtract the total child margin from the total width to find the usable width
                usableWidth = (1 - ((($(this).find("img").length) - 1) * margin));

                // for each child img of "selector" - add a width/height as value in the ratios array
                ratios = [];
                $(this).find("img").each(function () {
                    ratios.push(($(this).attr('width')) / ($(this).attr('height')));
                });

                // sum all the ratios for later divison
                ratioSum = 0;
                $.each(ratios, function () {
                    ratioSum += parseFloat(this) || 0;
                });

                lineArray = [];
                $.each(ratios, function (i) {
                    obj = {
                        // divide each item in the ratios array by the total array
                        // as set that as the css width in percentage
                        width: ((ratios[i] / ratioSum) * usableWidth) * 100 + "%",
                        height: ((ratios[i] / ratioSum) * usableWidth) * 100 + "%",
                        // set the margin-right equal to the parent margin-bottom
                        marginRight: marginRight
                    };
                    lineArray.push(obj);
                });
                lineArray[lineArray.length - 1].marginRight = "0%";
                // alert(lineArray[lineArray.length - 1].marginRight);
                masterArray.push(lineArray);
            });

            $(selector).each(function (i) {
                $(this).find("img").each(function (x) {
                    $(this).css({
                        "width": masterArray[i][x].width,
                        "margin-right": masterArray[i][x].marginRight
                    });
                });
                $(this).find(".text").each(function (x) {
                    $(this).css({
                        "width": masterArray[i][x].width,
                        /*"height": masterArray[i][x].height,*/
                        "margin-right": masterArray[i][x].marginRight                        
                    });
                });
            });

        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            picRow(".image-row");
        });
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    /*width:100px;*/
    display:block;
}
.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    color:#9CBDBE;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:30pt;
    background-color:#fff;
    width: 100px;
    /*height: 50px;*/
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1%;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.text:hover {
    opacity:0.8;
}

img {
    z-index:1;
}

.image-row {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1% 0;
}
.image-row img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  float: left;
}
.image-row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-row">
    <a href="#1" class="wrapper">
      <span class="text">Hover text</span>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/768x960" width="768" height="960"/>
    </a>
    <a href="#2" class="wrapper">
      <span class="text">Hover text</span>
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/1280x851" width="1280" height="851"/>
    </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this with CSS(refer other's answers) but if you want to do with Jquery You can do something like this. get the height of each image and apply it to their corresponding .text class.

```
$(selector).each(function (i) {

            $(this).find("img").each(function (x) {
                $(this).css({
                    "width": masterArray[i][x].width,
                    "margin-right": masterArray[i][x].marginRight
                });

            });
            $(this).find(".text").each(function (x) {
                            var imgHeight = $(this).parent().find("img").height();
                $(this).css({
                    "width": masterArray[i][x].width,
                    "height": imgHeight,
                    "margin-right": masterArray[i][x].marginRight                        
                });
            });
        });
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shuaibkhan1911/crw2bs15/7/)

Comment: When expanding the window, the overlay height breaks and does not fill the entire image anymore.

Comment: just add $( window ).resize(function() {
      picRow(".image-row");
    });   . see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/shuaibkhan1911/crw2bs15/9/

Comment: Any idea how to vertically align the hover text so it's in the center?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this CSS. I give the a tag `.wrapper` a width and height so that it can contain the span tag. Then the span stag `.text', I displayed block it then 100% the width and height so that it will occupy the space of the a tag. And lastly, I positioned absolute the image.

Please check my css code below:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    display:block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    color:#9CBDBE;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:30pt;
    background-color:#fff;
    /* width: 100px; */
    /*height: 50px;*/
    text-align: center;
    /* padding: 1%; */
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    left: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.text:hover {
    opacity:0.8;
}

img {
    z-index:1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.image-row {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1% 0;
}
.image-row img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  float: left;
}
.image-row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the images are not on the same row anymore. Check fiddle here: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ripsey/w18qc679/4/)

Comment: Ahhh okay, can you please display inline-block the .wrapper class instead of block...

Answer (score 0):

add this.. i just changed text position values.
**css**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    width:auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
.text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    color:#9CBDBE;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:30pt;
    background-color:#fff;
    width: 100px;
    /*height: 50px;*/
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1%;
    z-index: 10;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}
.text:hover {
    opacity:0.8;
}

img {
    z-index:1;
}

.image-row {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1% 0;
}
.image-row img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  float: left;
}
.image-row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this effect can be achieved in just CSS.

Here's my solution:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.imgWrapper { position: absolute; }

.imgWrapper::before {
  transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.imgWrapper:hover::before {
  background: red;
}

.imgWrapper:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.middle {
  transition: all ease-in-out .2s;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: #fff;
  padding: .5em;
}

.middle span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgRow">
  <div class="imgWrapper">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300" />
    <div class="middle">
      <span>Hello I am some text!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```